# Laravel 5.4 whereDate in Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

How to use whereMonth, whereDate in Eloquent ORM? (I know it can in DB query). Im using 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use all the methods from DB query in  Eloquent models, Check the following samples you can easily capture it. Both the samples, produce the same result

**Using query builder**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereDate('created_at', '2016-12-31')
                ->get();
```

**Using model**

```
$users = Users::whereDate('created_at', '2016-12-31')
                ->get();
```